# How extract all url from text in c# (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating an asp.net mvc application, where there is a text box where users can type text which may include some urls, on server i want to parse that text and extract all urls avable in it.

**possible text**

```
abc.com, xyz.com, http://foo.com
baar.com 
http://baz.com, www.foobar.com
mosso.com
http://subfoo.foo.com
bar.baz.com
foobar.net baaz2.com  morebaaz.com
```

**Expected Output  array**

```
abc.com
xyz.com
foo.com 
baar.com
baz.com
foobar.com
mosso.com
subfoo.foo.com
bar.baz.com   
foobar.net 
baaz2.com  
morebaaz.com
```

Comment: Did you mean domain names, or proper URLs like `foo.org/bar.htm`? What about IP addresses? Strictly .com, or any TLD?

Comment: The text MAY include urls, or are all elements urls separated by commas?

Comment: @p.campbell: proper urls, ignore ips, any TLDs

Comment: @ajc: the text may include urls.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for space. Added Replace(" ",",") to account for " " separation. This works for multiple " " as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
string[] domains = text.Replace(" ",",").Replace("http://", "").Replace("www.", "").Replace("ftp://", "").Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then you can check each string for a valid url

```
public static bool isValidUrl(string url)
{
    string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return reg.IsMatch(url);
}
```

Hope it helps...

EDIT: Sorry, the validation failed..Fixed it now...

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to set the delimiter. Looks like you're using commas, so that should be easy enough.

```
var urlArray = inputString.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Then you can loop through each string and check to see if a url needs to be trimmed.

```
foreach (var urlString in urlArray)
{
    if (urlString.Contains("http://")) // or other things you want to filter out
    {
        urlString = urlString.Substring(urlString.IndexOf("http://") + 7)
    }
}
```

Now you can display each string in the array!

Comment: Shoot, just read your comments. You could search `Contains(".com")` instead?

Comment: there is no guarantee that urls are separated by 'comma', they may be just separated by space